# Looking for help on errors on my C++ code for functions and arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

For my project in C++, I have been struggling with this project for a couple weeks now, and I feel like I have just confused myself with what I have added to this code.  Can anyone give me some guidance as to what I'm doing wrong?  Here are the errors I am getting right now:
151 29 [Error] could not convert '(FruitList*)(& itemsList)' from 'FruitList*' to 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}'
152 35 [Error] could not convert '(FruitList*)(& itemsList)' from 'FruitList*' to 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}'

Thanks!

I apologize if the code spacing is all messed up, this is my first post and I kept getting errors on how my code was spaced?  Sorry in advance!

```
    #include <iostream> //allows data to output to the screen
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    //function prototypes
    void showFruitList (string);
    void getData(string, int);


    class Customer//create a class called customer
    {
    private://private section

    //string all private variables
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string streetAddress;
    string city;

    string state;

    string zipCode;

    public: //public sections
    void setFName (string fName)//public function to set first name
    {
        firstName = fName;
    }

    string getFName ()//public function to get first name
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    void setLName (string lName)//public function to set last name
    {
        lastName = lName;
    }

    string getLName ()//public function to get last name
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    void setStreetAddress (string sAddress)//public function to set street               `       address
    {
        streetAddress = sAddress;
    }

    string getStreetAddress()//public function to get street address
    {
        return streetAddress;
    }

    void setCity (string cty)//public function to set city
    {
        city = cty;
    }

    string getCity()//public function to get city
    {
        return city;
    }
    void setState (string sT)//public function to set state
    {
        state = sT;
    }

    string getState ()//public function to get state
    {
        return state;
    }
    void setZipCode (string zip)//public function to set zip code
    {
        zipCode = zip;
    }

    string getZipCode()//public function to get zip code
    {
        return zipCode;
    }

    };

         struct FruitList //good for outputting lists of things to be called    `           `in main function
        {
        string fruitItem; //string type
        float fruitCostPP; //double type since prices for in decimal form   `          `(fruit cost per pound)

         };

    //Establish customer registration and display a list of products
    int main()
    {
    //declare variables 
    const int SIZE = 80;// assign value of 80 to SIZE
    char firstName[ SIZE ];


    Customer customer1 = Customer();//pulls from class Customer

    string input;//welcome message and customer info input area
    cout << "Welcome to Dried Fruit Central \n" <<endl;
    cout << "Please enter your first name: "<< endl;//prompts user to enter   `      `their first name
    getline(cin, input);//user enters their first name

    customer1.setFName(input);//pulls from class Customer

    cout << "\nPlease enter your last name: " << endl; //promts user to  `                    `       `enter their last name
    getline(cin, input);//user enters their last name

    customer1.setLName(input);//pulls from class Customer

    cout << "\nHello " << customer1.getFName() << "!"<< endl;// greeting to  `      `user using their first name

    cout << "\nPlease enter your street address: "<< endl;//prompts user for   `       `their street address
    getline(cin, input);//user enters their street address

    customer1.setStreetAddress(input);//pulls from class Customer

    cout << "\nPlease enter your city: "<< endl;//promts user to enter their   `       `city
    getline(cin, input);//user enters their city

    customer1.setCity(input);//pulls from class Customer

    cout << "\nPlease enter your state abbreviation: "<< endl;// prompts `       `       `user to enter their state abbreviation
    getline(cin, input); //user enters their state abbreviation

    customer1.setState(input);//pulls from class Customer

    cout << "\nPlease enter your zip code: "<< endl;//promts user to enter  `       `their zip code
    getline(cin, input);//user enters their zipcode

    customer1.setZipCode(input);//pulls from class Customer

    cout << "\nThank you " << customer1.getFName() << ", you are now  `              `       `registered and can begin shopping with \nDried Fruit Central! \n"<<   `    `        endl;// lets customer know they are now registered and can begin  `    `        shopping
    cout << "\nHere is a list of our dried fruit available for purchase and  `       `price per pound: \n"<< endl;//OUtput to customers the list of dried  `    `       will be displayed as well as the price per pound

    FruitList itemsList[8]; // 8 items on the menu
    int itemNum = 0;//
    char inputItemNum;//customers input fruit item number
    vector<int> customerOrder;//customers order

    while (true)//begin while loop
    {
        float totalCost=0;//double due to decimal amounts
        getData(itemsList, 8); //pull from function getData
        showFruitList(itemsList, 8); // pull function showFruitList

        cout<<"Enter your orders. Press Enter after every input. Enter 0 to  `           `end"<<endl;//customer inputs item numbers 
        do
        {

            while((cin>>itemNum).fail() || itemNum < 0 || itemNum > `    `   `             `9)//while loop to prevent customer from inputting the wrong item  `             `number
            {
                cout<<"Enter correct item number : ";//error message
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore();
            }
            customerOrder.push_back(itemNum - 1);
        }while(itemNum != 0);

        cout<<endl<<"You ordered"<<endl;//displays order total and items  `   `           purchased
        for(int i = 0; i < customerOrder.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            cout<<itemsList[customerOrder.at(i)].fruitItem<<"\t\t$ " `   `  `          `<<itemsList[customerOrder.at(i)].fruitCostPP<<endl;
            totalCost += itemsList[customerOrder.at(i)].fruitCostPP;//all  `   `           calculations
        }

         cout <<endl<<"Your order total is: $" << totalCost << endl <<  `    `           endl;//displays total cost
        cout << "Input 'n' for a new order or 'Q' to quit \t";//allows users  `           `to start new order or quit this order
        cin >> inputItemNum;

        if (inputItemNum == 'q' || inputItemNum == 'Q')
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else while (inputItemNum != 'n')//else while loop for error  `  `   `           selection
        {
            cout << "Please make a valid selection.\t";//output error for  `  `            valid selection to be entered
            cin >> inputItemNum;
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
       }
      //    system("pause");
       return 0;
       }



        void showFruitList(FruitList list[], int size) //calls in structure  `          `of fruit menu and price together to be displayed when called in main
        {
       cout << "Type the number of the items that you would like.""\n";
       cout << "After each selection, press Enter." "\n";
       cout << "To add multiple orders of the same fruit enter the same item    `         `number." "\n\n\n" << endl;
       cout << "When you are done, type 0 and press Enter to get your order   `           `total." "\n\n\n" << endl;
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) //goes with size of list 8, and adds a    `         `.) and $ in front of each item
       {
        cout << "\t\t" << i + 1 << ") " << list[i].fruitItem << "$ " <<    `    `           list[i].fruitCostPP << endl; //structure.   i+1 to start num at 1  `    `           rather than 0
        cout << "\n";
        }
        return;
        }
       void getData(FruitList list[], int size) //two arrays that list the   `         `item and one for the price 0-8
       {
        list[0].fruitItem = "Apricots.\t\t"; //items array starts at 0.  `    `           output     at 1.
        list[0].fruitCostPP = 1.75;//price array starts at 0
        list[1].fruitItem = "Apples.\t\t";
         list[1].fruitCostPP = 1.25;
         list[2].fruitItem = "Bananas.\t\t";
         list[2].fruitCostPP = 1.25;
         list[3].fruitItem = "Cherries.\t\t";
         list[3].fruitCostPP = 2.25;
         list[4].fruitItem = "Cranberries.\t\t";
         list[4].fruitCostPP = 1.25;
         list[5].fruitItem = "Mangos.\t\t";
         list[5].fruitCostPP = 1.75;
         list[6].fruitItem = "Peaches.\t\t";
          list[6].fruitCostPP = 1.25;
          list[7].fruitItem = "Strawberries.\t";
          list[7].fruitCostPP = 1.75;

          }
```

Comment: You can forward-declare a type (e.g. `FruitList`) so that the compiler knows it exists, but you can't actually use any members of it until you've told the compiler how it's defined. So your `struct FruitList` definition needs to appear **before** any members of the structure are referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the *function* prototypes, but with the *structure* definition.

If you want to actually *use* a structure, it must be defined in full. It's okay to put function definitions (the implementation) after you call the functions, but for structures that's not possible.

To declare an actual variable of a structure the compiler needs the full definition of the structure, or the compiler won't know what members it contains or how big it is.

So to solve your problem don't have a simple forward declaration of the structure at the top, put the whole structure definition there.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I removed the prototype for the struct and moved the struct function back to the top and that took care of that error.  But, of course I now have two new errors:   151 29 [Error] could not convert '(FruitList*)(& itemsList)' from 'FruitList*' to 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}'
152 35 [Error] could not convert '(FruitList*)(& itemsList)' from 'FruitList*' to 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}'     I'm trying to scan my book for information on what I did, I have struggled with this class for a couple weeks and I'm so confused at this point.

Comment: @KatherinePhipps Is the `showFruitList` function taking a `FruitList` pointer as argument? Should it do that? And if you have an array like `itemsList` then taking the address of it (i.e. `&itemsList`) will in most cases not work as you expect.Arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element, if you have a function that expects a pointer to some structure, it's enough to just pass the array, as is, as argument to the function.

Comment: The next thing I need to do once I fix all the errors in this, is to provide the use of a pointer, without worrying about allocating dynamic memory.  I only need a demonstration of the understanding of how pointers work in the C++ Language.  I am still learning about pointers, and now stressing about how I am going to add that and where.  Are you suggesting that I need one in order for this to work, or that I can not put one in here properly now?